# Concatenate value from textarea to another place

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following textarea

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="projectname"></textarea>
```

And I want to get its value and concatenate with the value inside this:

```
<h1 id="team_title"> Team name </h1>
```

So basically, after writing "china123" in my `textarea` I would get in my `h1` the following = `Team name - china123`

I have tried the following:

```
function myFunction() {
    var k = document.getElementById('team_title').innerHTML;
    var m = document.getElementById('projectname').value;
    var x = k.concat(" -" + m);
    document.getElementById('team_title').innerHTML = x;
}
```

And I add it as a `oninput` attribute on the textarea. But the problem seems to be that after each input it gets the following

```
 Team name - c -ch - chi - chin - china - china1 - china12 - china123
```

Although my desired output in the `h1` tag is:

```
Team name - china123
```

Comment: Can You use jquery or just pure js?

Comment: Although I could use jquery, I have no knowledge of that. Would prefer if someone helped me out using js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the original prefix in the `data-prefix` property of `h1`

```
<h1 id="team_title" data-prefix="Team name "> Team name </h1>
```

Now keep appending value to the `data-prefix` value

```
function myFunction() {
    var k = document.getElementById('team_title').getAttribute( "data-prefix" ); //observe the change here
    var m = document.getElementById('projectname').value;
    var x = k.concat(" -" + m);
    document.getElementById('team_title').innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Didn't know about data-prefix .

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string on the `-` and then concat them together

```
 var input = k.split('-')[0];
  var x = input.concat(" -" + m);
```

Hope this helps :)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var k = document.getElementById('team_title').innerHTML;
  var m = document.getElementById('projectname').value;
  var input = k.split('-')[0];
  var x = input.concat(" -" + m);
  document.getElementById('team_title').innerHTML = x;

}
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="projectname" onkeyup="myFunction()"></textarea>

<h1 id="team_title"> Team name </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must be calling the function onchange, which means everytime you type the function will concatenate, you have 2 choices:
1. make a button or an event that will concatenate AFTER the whole input.
2. save the h1 value and concatenate with that value unchanged (data-* attribute)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use concat for this.
The value of variable m is already converted as a string. In Javascript you can easily add these strings by using the + line.

```
function myFunction() {
 var k = document.getElementById('team_title').getAttribute( "data-prefix" ); //observe the change here
 var m = document.getElementById('projectname').value;
 var x = k + ' - ' + m;
 document.getElementById('team_title').innerHTML = x;
}
```